# Problem with equation rewriting of differential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Anyone who's able to explain how this equation is done? And how it goes from it's initial state to the final?[Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKwP4.jpg)

Comment: I believe your question would be more appreciated if you wrote down the equations in your post instead of giving us a link

Comment: @LionelRicci I don't know how to do the math in here, sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the [pendulum equation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjjtJPriYzMAhUpt4MKHcZgBvcQ0gIIPSgCMAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPendulum_(mathematics)%23Arbitrary-amplitude_period&usg=AFQjCNHlpfTlGcuQ6dkT77jVa8a8WPmIxg) $$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\sqrt{\frac{2g}r(\cos\theta-\cos\theta_0)}$$
You can make the half-angle substitution to get
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=2\sqrt{\frac{g}r\left(\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta_0}2\right)-\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)\right)}$$
Then if you let $\sin\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)=\sin\left(\frac{\theta_0}2\right)\sin\phi$ the equation is transformed into
$$\frac{d\phi}{dt}=\sqrt{\frac gr}\sqrt{1-\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta_0}2\right)\sin^2\phi}$$
So you can see that it reduces to an elliptic integral of the first kind.